# Loop through array and delete all duplicates in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, duplicates

I need to loop through an array called @ads and delete all objects in it that are duplicates of one another. how do i do this?

Comment: if it an array my not use `.uniq!`

Answer (score 4):

```
@ads = @ads.uniq
```

or

```
@ads.uniq!
```

Answer (score 4):

The below code will give you the result uniqic by id.

```
@ads = @ads.uniq{|ad| ad.id}
```

Comment: It accepts a block? You really learn every day on this site :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev guess it started in 1.9